# How do I increase the size of file descriptors on mac

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server

I am getting an error from squid

```
WARNING! Your cache is running out of filedescriptors
```

What should i do in my mac to prevent this error?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use something similar to:

```
# sysctl -w kern.maxfiles = nr
# sysctl -w kern.maxfileperproc = nr
```

To make it persistent edit /etc/sysctl.conf like this

```
kern.maxfiles=nr
kern.maxfileperproc = nr
```

Later method needs reboot or reload via sysctl.

You may also need to raise the ulimit settings for regular users:

```
ulimit -S n nr
```